# Stack Exchange API is not returning the close vote counts for questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

When you visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581574/flattening-multiple-pngs-with-php) question *(with proper privs)* you can see that there are **2** close votes cast for it.

However, if you access the information for this question using the Stack Exchange API you get the following:

```
[question_id] => 17581574
[creation_date] => 1373493187
[score] => 0
[title] => Flattening multiple PNGs with php
[link] => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581574/flattening-multiple-pngs-with-php
[is_answered] => 
[close_vote_count] => 0
[reopen_vote_count] => 0
[delete_vote_count] => 0
```

It does not show the correct count; actually, no count at all for the close votes is shown. I've fetched the same data from 400+ questions in the cv-pls [backlog](http://cvbacklog.gordon-oheim.biz/), and not a single one shows the close vote count.

However, they DO show delete vote counts. So I do not think it is a permissions issue since it would not allow that info to be fetched. I have not checked to see if the same is to be said for the re-open vote count. The filter is set to fetch it otherwise it would not even be returned in the JSON response.

- Why are the close vote counts not being populated in the API?
- Is this a bug, or are there additional steps needed to acquire that info in an API call?

Forgive my ignorance if I have overlooked some API documentation regarding this.

Comment: maybe because of [on-hold] change?

Comment: @hjpotter92: are you saying the recent close-vote changes have effected the API?

Comment: @crypticツ probably, I'm looking into it.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: yay they are now showing up. Turns out re-open votes were also broken, they too are showing up now. However, some questions the reopen_vote_count field is not being returned in the JSON response now. It should return as it is specified to do so via the filter, even if the count is at 0.

Comment: subtle... digging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.